# infinite loading for json data in flutter

Tags: json, database, flutter, null

EDIT - "When I tried to run print(snapshot.error), It gave "type int is not a subtype of type string""

I am trying to get json data from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RahulBagdiOfficial/rto_app_flutter/master/assets/json/applyonline.json

using https request package then parsing it into json data,

I am using it to build a list using ListView.builder
that if the data is null return CircularProgressIndicator
and if it contain data return list

The problem is This

[image]

its Stuck on loading

This is my code

```
class ApplyOnline extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ApplyOnlineState createState() => _ApplyOnlineState();
}

class _ApplyOnlineState extends State<ApplyOnline> {
  @override
  Future<List<ApplyOnlineList>> _getapplyonlinelist() async {
    var data = await http.get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RahulBagdiOfficial/rto_app_flutter/master/assets/json/applyonline.json");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<ApplyOnlineList> applyonlinelist = [];
    for (var i in jsonData) {
      ApplyOnlineList applyonlineobject =
          ApplyOnlineList(i['index'], i['string'], i['url']);
      applyonlinelist.add(applyonlineobject);
    }
    print(applyonlinelist.length);
    return applyonlinelist;
  }

  Widget customURLButton(String text, String URL, Icon icon) {
    ;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff655ee6),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff655ee6),
        title: Text("Apply Online"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getapplyonlinelist(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              } if(snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].string),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ApplyOnlineList {
  final int index;
  final String url;
  final String string;

  ApplyOnlineList(this.url, this.index, this.string);
}
```

Comment: it is helpful to attach your logs along with question

Comment: Hello, are you sure this Function of _getapplyonlinelist() is called? from what I see it is not called, that's why you only got null, try it put it before `return Scaffold()` and try to print out

Answer (score 0):

You should pass reference of the future since you're not accepting any params in future:

```
future: _getapplyonlinelist
```

Check all the connection state before getting into snapshot.

And for checking snapshot, You can do this way:

```
if(snapshot.hasData) {
// return something
} else if(snapshot.hasError) {
// play with error
}
return CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: Did you try that? It should give you a syntax error.

Comment: After reading your Answer what I did is I added print snapshot.error.                                                      I got type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're checking for null, and returning the widget, doing this doesn't allow the `FutureBuilder` to rebuild because you're not checking its connection state, so the state of the data won't update. Try this instead.

```
 ...
         FutureBuilder(
            future: _getapplyonlinelist(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshot.hasData) 
              {
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].string),
                    );
                );
              }
...
```

Checking the `ConnectionState` will let the future builder resolve the future properly.

Comment: What does checking the state have to do with the FutureBuilder resolving the future?

Comment: Checking `ConnectionState` ensures that you wait till the future completes. If you instead compare the data to null and render it,the builder will build it and the data will be null

Answer (score 0):

```
future: _getapplyonlinelist(),
```

Don't do this. This way, every time your `build` function is called, your Future will start over. You need to start it *once* and then wait for it.

In your state, outside the build method, have a variable to hold the future. Assign `_getapplyonlinelist()` to this variable *once*, probably in the `void initState ()` method. Then use that variable in your `build` method. That way, no matter how often the build method is called, it will not start the Future over and over and over.

In your state class:

```
Future<List<ApplyOnlineList>> waitingForOnlineList;

void initState () {
  waitingForOnlineList = _getapplyonlinelist();
}
```

... and then in your `build` method:

```
future: waitingForOnlineList,
```